# Build a countdown using a loop and sleep method in php

Tags: php, sleep, countdown

I am trying to make PHP print out a sequence numbers after a one second pause of execution using the sleep() method but then the code pauses execution for that duration and then executes the loop in a flash.

**What i was expecting**

I was expecting that for each iteration in that loop,it would print out a number and then call `sleep()` which would delay the code for a sec and then print out the next number and then delay and so on and so forth..

**Code am using**

```
<?php
$myarr=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
foreach($myarr as $p){ 
//print out a number and then pause for a sec
echo "$p <br/>";
sleep(1);
/*the line above instead makes the thread sleep for one second and then prints the rest of the numbers in a flash instead of printing a single number and pausing and so on and so forth*/
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you visiting this in a browser, or using the command line? If a browser (which I'm guessing you are since you're echoing `<br/>`), then PHP is run server side and then sent to the user upon completion of the entire script, which means your sleep just makes the script take longer. You would need Javascript to achieve the behavior you want.

Comment: @David, oKay, am using a browser with xampp to run the php script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve it by flushing the output before the sleep

The code will be :

```
<?php

$myarr=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
foreach($myarr as $p){ 
//print out a number and then pause for two seconds

    ob_start();

                  echo "$p <br/>";

    $size = ob_get_length();
    ob_end_flush();
    @ob_flush();
    flush();
    
 sleep(2);

}
?>
```

Comment: Implementing this , will be back in a sec

Comment: Worked like a charm , lemme complete the web utility i was making for a client now, thanks to you

Answer (score 2):

Basically PHP does do exactly what you want... just not on the browser...
A way to go is via ob_flush :

```
<?php

if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

for ($i = 0; $i<10; $i++){

        echo "<br>" . $i;
        echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";

        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(2);
}

echo "Done.";

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

This will print a number every 2 seconds... but it's eh... not the best at what it does.... at least the first 4-5 seconds - meaning 0,1 and maybe 2 are already printed when we start seeing the sleep do it's trick.

Comment: OKay, so what exactly is the ob_flush function and what does it do?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php ob_flush — Flush (send) the output buffer

Comment: Since PHP is a backend server language it doesn't update the browser in the same way things are printed in the terminal, these function(s) (flush family) actually do a flush of the data while it is being created to the browser - this combined with sleep allows to really see the data as it's being printed.